# Hosting my node.js project on Live server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting

I am new to node.js, I have created a project using create-react-app with react, react-redux and react-router.
Now, I want to upload my project to a live server so, I was wondering if I am required to upload the **node_modules** folder to the server or is it all incorporated in the **build** folder somehow?

I have searched for answers but only got results related to "Pros and cons of including node modules in your git repository"

Comment: That would be depending on how the build folder is created (i.e. what command is used to generate the build)

Comment: You won't need to upload your _node_modules_ directory. Once your project is built you can then upload its *dist* folder to your server (this step will depend on the hosting provider you choose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to upload node_modules into the server.
If you are using a web service like HEROKU to deploy or AWS I recommend you use it so.
so the bottom line is that you don't need to upload the node_modules file. just commit the repo to a git hub and you can link it to your Heroku account so that the site will be live.

so what happens here is that when you not include the node_module file, you have seen that package.json file right ?

You can see all the dependencies that you have used to work on your project like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "generate-password": "^1.4.1",
    "js-base64": "^2.4.9",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mongojs": "^2.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.12",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0"

     }
```

so that means using that package.json file the server will add and install all the dependencies that need to run the application. And of course this will run on a node environment only. So you will need to select it in the web service you are using. In Heroku you can deploy your app to a  node environment. You it's easy you just need to go there and read their documentation on how to do it.you can try digital ocen too they also provide such facilities

> heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com) amazon node app deploy [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/) digital ocean docs
>   [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/one-click-apps/node-js)

Comment: Thank you for the info.